# ModelMapper throws an error when maps one List to Map but works correctly with another List that is actually the same

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapper v3.1.0 for my project on SpringBoot v2.7.4.

There are three classes: `DoctorEntity`, `Doctor`(Model) and `DoctorDTO`:

```java
public class Doctor {
    // Key is ID of the value
    private Map<Long, AppointmentInterface> appointments;
    ...
}
```

```java
public class DoctorDTO {
    private List<AppointmentDto> appointments;
    ...
}
```

```java
public class DoctorEntity {
    private List<AppointmentEntity> appointmentEntities
    ...
}
```

As you can see `Doctor`'s property is `Map`, while others are `List`s.

To help `ModelMapper` map 'List' into 'Map' I had to override the methods:
**DoctorDTO -> Doctor:**

```java
@Override
protected void mapSpecificFieldsToModelFromDto(DoctorDto source, Doctor destination) {

    if (source.getAppointments() != null)
        destination.setAppointments(source.getAppointments()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AppointmentDto::getId,
                        elem -> mapper.map(elem, Appointment.class))));
}
```

**DoctorEntity -> Doctor:**

```java
@Override
protected void mapSpecificFieldsToModelFromEntity(DoctorEntity source, Doctor destination) {

    if (source.getAppointmentEntities() != null)
        destination.setAppointments(source.getAppointmentEntities()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AppointmentEntity::getId,
                        elem -> mapper.map(elem, Appointment.class))));
}
```

I have written two tests to check the mapping to `Doctor`:

**1(Passes):**

```java
@Autowired
private Mapper<DoctorEntity, Doctor, DoctorDto> doctorMapper;

@Test
void mapEntityToModel() {
    DoctorEntity doctorEntity = new DoctorEntity(1L,
            ...
            List.of(new AppointmentEntity(1L,
                            LocalDate.now(),
                            AppointmentState.OPEN,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null)
            ));

    Doctor doctor = doctorMapper.toModelFromEntity(doctorEntity);


    doctorEntity.getAppointments().forEach(a -> assertTrue(doctor.getAppointments().containsKey(a.getId())));
}
```

**2(Fails):**

```java
@Autowired
private Mapper<DoctorEntity, Doctor, DoctorDto> doctorMapper;

void mapDtoToModel() {
        DoctorDto doctorDto = new DoctorDto(1L,
                ...
                List.of(new AppointmentDto(1L,
                                LocalDate.now(),
                                AppointmentState.OPEN,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null)
                ));

        Doctor doctor = doctorMapper.toModelFromDto(doctorDto);

        doctorDto.getAppointments().forEach(a -> assertTrue(doctor.getAppointments().containsKey(a.getId())));
    }
```

The issue occurs when `ModelMapper` tries to map `DoctorDTO` to `Doctor` but throws an error:

```
1) Failed to instantiate instance of destination java.util.Map. Ensure that java.util.Map has a non-private no-argument constructor.
```

**However**, it maps `DoctorEntity` to `Doctor` correctly without throwing any error.

I've tried to change `Map` interface to `HashMap` and **it did the trick**. But I can't understand why does `ModelMapper` maps one `List` to `Map` and doesn't map the other when they're the same.

Comment: The second test checks mapping from Doctor to DoctorEntity, not the other way, so it doesn't test any of the two methods. Probably both of them don't work.

Comment: @Mafor I've edited the code of tests. Initially I pasted the wrong test :\